# Can Chrome extension and offline MS Office plugin work together

Tags: plugins, google-chrome-extension, ms-office

I am planning to build a Chrome extension and want to be able to start it up and run it with an offline MS Office plugin (text highlight and right click). But I wonder if this is possible because Chrome and desktop office are in different ecosystems. A Chrome extension developer has told me that this is not possible, but I am still hoping that there is a way to make it happen.

Comment: You can write an additional app (using any language, for example python or node.js) that controls the plugin and communicates with your extension via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: So it's possible! Thank you very much.

Comment: A further question. Will the Office plugin be able to start up the extension even when Chrome is not already open?

Comment: I have no idea how that plugin is programmatically organized.

Comment: I am asking about MS plugins in general--whether it is possible to organize it that way.